# Help identify an 8-pin laptop battery connector

Tags: batteries, identification, connector

I'm trying to identify a laptop battery connector so I can replace the connector on a functioning battery which has an incorrect connector. It looks like it might be a JST connector, but there are so many types!

The laptop is a Lenovo Yoga S730-13IWL.

Here's the front and back:

[image]

[image]

Here's the top, best as I can manage:

[image]

And here's the input, which is labelled Alltop 1823 (Alltop's website didn't help me much):

[image]

I'd appreciate any help or leads!

Here's a photo of the battery lead from an online store:

[image]

Comment: More relevant would be if you used that ruler (or better yet a calliper) to measure the center to center distance between the two outermost wires, then divide by 8. Then you get the pitch, what is it? 1.00mm? 1.27mm?

Comment: @Lundin ah, clever! I don't have calipers, but I get 9mm, so I suppose it might be 1.125mm?

Comment: @Lundin I've made another measure and it might be more like 9.1 or 9.2. Hard to say with a ruler as inaccurate as mine, unfortunately.

Comment: Standard pitches are 1.00mm and 1.27mm. Less common but existing is 1.25mm. It will be impossible to tell if it's 1.27mm or 1.25mm without a good calliper.

Comment: It's definitely wider than 8mm (a 1.00mm pitch) and definitely smaller than 10.16 (a 1.27mm pitch), if that helps at all.

Comment: Anyway, if you know the pitch you can search for 1.xx mm board-to-wire crimp connectors. That should narrow it down. I'm not certain that this is JST, though that's one of the first places to check.

Comment: I just realised that it should be (distance between left and rightmost pin) / (number of pins - 1), which gives a pitch of 1.30mm or perhaps indeed 1.27mm.

Comment: Ah yeah that's correct of course.

Comment: @lundin fencepost error:  should have divided by 7

Comment: Pitch is 1.25 or 1.27 mm. Manufacturer is [AllTop](http://www.alltopconnector.com/en-global/product/products#follow_area) but the website doesn't list that particular connector. You can try contacting them: http://www.alltopconnector.com/en-global/Page/contact_information

Comment: Molex PicoBlade?